# Add legend to plot3d in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, legend

I have visualized cluster result as shown below:

```
plot3d(RFM[,2:4],col= RFM$CLASS)
```

[image]

now how can I add legend for cluster labels (CLASS) with corresponding colors?

My data is like following :

[image]

edit:

I have tried legend3d and text3d and I can add legend, but the problem is that I can not be sure the color of legend is the same as the color of the shape as they are corresponding to a given class !, how can I do it in correct way ?

Solution for me: 
I got a solution that worked for me, as I said I wanted to get sure colors remain same on both legend and shape, so I did this:

```
   plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==1,2:4],col = "red" )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==2,2:4],col = "blue", add=T )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==3,2:4],col = "green", add=T )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==4,2:4],col = "cyan", add=T )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==5,2:4],col = "yellow", add=T )

legend3d("topright", legend = paste('Type', c('1','2','3','4','5')), pch = 16, col = c("red","blue","green","cyan","yellow")  , cex=1, inset=c(0.02))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution I found for this problem,As I said I wanted to get sure colors remain same on both legend and shape, :

```
lot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==1,2:4],col = "red" )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==2,2:4],col = "blue", add=T )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==3,2:4],col = "green", add=T )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==4,2:4],col = "cyan", add=T )
plot3d(RFM[RFM$CLASS==5,2:4],col = "yellow", add=T )

legend3d("topright", legend = paste('Type', c('1','2','3','4','5')), pch = 16, col = c("red","blue","green","cyan","yellow")  , cex=1, inset=c(0.02))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `legend3d`:

```
legend3d("topright", legend = paste('Type', c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')), pch = 16, col = RFM$CLASS, cex=1, inset=c(0.02))
```

Comment: I used this but all colors are the same (Blue here)

Comment: Check if RFM$CLASS is a factor (I guess you already checked it). I've never used this type of legends so I'm not sure how to fix your issue. Try with col = rainbow(5) to see if colours match with your data.

Comment: I tried this and as you know the problem is that i can not be sure if the rainbow(5) give me the same colors as used in the diagram, what is the reason people give down voates ?

Comment: I only have two more ideas... try: ´col = c(1:5)[RFM$CLASS]´  (within the `legend3d` and whithin `plot3d`) or  `color <- c("red","green","blue", "gray", "black")[RFM$CLASS]` and then `col = color`(Also within the `legend3d` and whithin `plot3d`) (This get use to work with normal plots). Hope anyone else could help. (Don't know why people is downvoating)

Comment: the reason was : RFM$CLASS is a vector that show the class number for each sample, and when I use it for col of legend3d, it just take the five first rows which there had same CLASS, I just Changed the code and got the solution, if you update the answer I will mark it as accepted